# How exlude some database records by checking another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I currently have this simple SQL statement to pull back the details of our last 100 quotes on our shopping cart:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    orders
JOIN customers ON orders.CustomerNumber = customers.CustomerNumber
WHERE
    STATUS = 'QUOTE'
ORDER BY
    orders.OrderNumber DESC
LIMIT 0,
 100
```

We also have a "comments" table where sometimes our staff add a set comment that says the customer does not want to be contacted. How can I modify my SQL to cross check the comments table to see if such a comment exists associated with the order number?

- **Table name:** comments
- **Columns:** OrderNumber (for the join), CommentText
- **Comment to look for and exclude from record set if exists:** "Do not
  contact"

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using MySQL and/or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use a `not exists` predicate:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    orders o
JOIN customers c ON o.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
WHERE
    STATUS = 'QUOTE'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM comments 
    WHERE CommentText = 'Do not contact' 
    AND OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber 
)
ORDER BY
    o.OrderNumber DESC
LIMIT 0, 100
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1ca2/3)

Comment: This works exactly as I want it - but it's quite slow. I'm having to use a NOT LIKE rather than = as the end of the comment can vary with the users initials also included. I think queries like this re always going to be a bit slow aren't they?

Comment: @JamesWilson Yes, if you have to do something like `where CommentText like '%Do not contact%' ` then it will be slow as you can't use indexes. The best way to solve it might be to store the "contact/don't contact" option as a separate value, but maybe that isn't possible.

Comment: Talking of moving goal posts!!! I haven't considered there being NO comment rows associated with an order row! I think the current code only returns orders where there is at least 1 comment, and it doesn't contain the DO not contact text. Sorry! Can it be modified?

Comment: @JamesWilson Your assumption is incorrect, this will return rows even when there are no comments at all. It just excludes those OrderNumbers for which there exists a comment "Do not contact". Look at this example and see how order 3 appears in the result even though it doesn't have any comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e35f0/1

Comment: Sorry I'm such a wally, I still had the "JOIN comments...." line from the other answer in my SQL. So we were both kind of right ;-) You more so!! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT    * 
FROM orders
JOIN customers ON orders.CustomerNumber = customers.CustomerNumber
JOIN comments ON orders.orderNumber = comments.orderNumber
WHERE STATUS = 'QUOTE'
and comments.commentText NOT LIKE '%Do not contact%'
ORDER BY orders.OrderNumber DESC
LIMIT 0, 100
```

Comment: There is a slight problem here. There could be other comments associated with the orders that have the "do not contact" comment also. So testing the code above I'm still seeing an Order row returned despite it having a comment of "do not contact" - may need to modify the SQL please? Appreciate the help!

Comment: @JamesWilson ahhh changing requirements how unusual in development, see update

Comment: or if you mean its a one to many relationship, go with the other answer

Comment: I think I need to choose the answer down stairs - really appreciate your help though!